# iOS 10, Swift 3 - change inactive bar item icon?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I was trying to find answer to my problem but I couldn't figure it out.
I've imported my own icons to icons assets which are white and in .png format and I want to use them in tab bar item. Everything works great but when the screen is inactive the icon is gray. I want it to be white as original. I've tried to change "render as" in assets but then the icon doesn't change when the screen gets active.
Is there any way to fix it? 
Thanks for all help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzDl3.png

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS-:

```
var image = UIImage(named:"your image")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```